# Solve differential equation using undetermined coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y'' - 2y' + y = x \sin (x)$$

I want to solve this differential equation using undetermined coefficient. I found the particular solution

$$y_c = Ae^x + B x e^x$$

because of the repeated root $(r-1)(r-1)$. So, my guess is

$$y_p = C x \cos(x) + E x \sin(x)$$

but the root is repeated twice so it become $y_p=(Cx \cos x+Ex \sin x)x^2$, is this true? Thank you!

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is wrong. Your particular solution is also wrong, the root only matters if it is equal to the coefficient in the exponential on the RHS, which in this case is $\pm i$. You should have checked this by substituting it in.

Comment: @ian My homogeneous solution is wrong?

Comment: Now it is not; perhaps I missed the factor of $x$ in the previous version.

Comment: @ian ok. The coefficient of exponent is 1, And the particular solution is $xcos x$ and $x sinx $, is this consider to be repeated twice?

Comment: The repetition of the root 1 has nothing to do with anything because the relevant exponential from the RHS is $e^{ix}$.

Comment: try $$y_p=A\cos(x)+Bx\cos(x)+C\sin(x)$$

Comment: @ian if there is no overlapping, is this true $y_p = C x \cos(x) + E x \sin(x)$ ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i didnt understand why there is $A cos x$ , and no overlapping here?

Comment: In general you will actually need a general linear function in front, not just a multiple of $x$. This is part of why going through complex exponentials is easier.

Comment: @ian general linear function? can you explain bit more?

Comment: The easy way to solve this is to take the imaginary part of the solution to $z''-2z'+z=x e^{ix}$; the paarticular solution to this equation is of the form $(Ax+B)e^{ix}$. That B usually is not 0. You still need this constant term even if you go through trig functions directly.

Comment: ok write $$(A+Bx)\cos(x)+C\sin(x)$$

Comment: @ian ok thanks so one is consider overlapping if the root is completely the same with the one in homogeneous solution? yeah i was forgot that x is $Ax+B$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thankyou so much! i was forgot $Ax+B$ part!!!

Comment: yeah you are welcome, nice that i could help you!